# How to render user picture from page.html.twig file

Tags: theming

I am using

> node.Owner

To print out things like user name, for instance to print the first name out (which is a custom field) it is simply.

> {{ node.Owner.field_first.value }}

However if I try to do the same for the user picture I get an error. I have tried

> {{ node.Owner.user_picture.value }}
>
> {{ node.Owner.user_picture}}
>
> {{ node.Owner.user_picture.0.value }}
>
> {{ node.Owner.user_picture.content }}

None of these work ?

Answer (score 1):

You can either do

`{{ node.author_picture.content }}`

or

`{{ content.author_picture }}`